# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'

Tags: python, pexpect

here is my code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect

obj=pexpect.spawn('ftp localhost')
print id.expect_exact('Name')
```

i am using kali linux and have also installed pexpect.i m also running an vsftpd ftp server.This is the error thats comes up when i run my program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./last.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/root/pexpect.py", line 3, in <module>
    id=pexpect.spawn('ftp localhost')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'
```

Comment: Make sure not to name your python file as `pexpect`

Comment: I have named the file last.py.Can you suggest any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You're also using filename pexpect.py in /root folder.